# Best way to read a stream to a delimiter and no farther

Tags: c#, stream

My code has to consume data from a NetworkStream, and the data read from the stream will contain three parts: metadata, a well-known delimiter, and data.

I'm trying to determine the most efficient way of reading from the NetworkStream, up to the end of the delimiter.  The metadata portion is generally measured in hundreds of bytes (but could be as small as 32 bytes), the delimiter is a specific 2-byte sequence, and the data could range from zero bytes to several gigabytes in size (the metadata provides information on the data length).  I should only read up to the delimiter, because the rest of the stream (containing payload data) needs to be used elsewhere, and NetworkStream doesn't support seek and the data may be so large that I can't dump it all into a MemoryStream.

I've been using the following, and it works, but it seems there could be a more efficient way of reading up to the delimiter.  Since the minimum metadata size is 32 bytes, I start with a 34-byte buffer (32 bytes of metadata + 2 bytes delimiter), read from the stream, and check for the delimiter.  If the delimiter is found (smallest possible metadata), the code then breaks and the balance of the stream contains the data.  If the delimiter is not found, the code then loops reading a single byte at a time, checking the last two bytes of the StringBuilder used to hold what has been read from the stream, until the delimiter is found at the end.

(code reduced for brevity, removed checking of negative cases, etc)

```
string delim = "__";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
byte[] initialBuffer = new byte[34];
int bytesRead = stream.Read(initialBuffer, 0, 34);  // yes I check bytesRead in the actual code
sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(initialBuffer);

while (true)
{
    string delimCheck = sb.ToString((sb.Length - 2), 2);
    if (delimCheck.Equals(delim)) break;
    else
    {
        buffer = new byte[1];
        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1); // yes I check bytesRead in the actual code
        sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
    }
}
```

The code works, but it seems really inefficient and slow to read one byte at a time to reach the end of the delimiter.  Is anything readily apparent that might better optimize this code?

Thanks!

Comment: _"there are times where there isn't data at all, and I might block waiting for data that will never arrive"_ -- that's only a problem because your entire architecture is wrong. Network I/O should be handled asynchronously. No thread should ever be blocked waiting on data. And if reading synchronously it's _impossible_ to prevent the thread from being blocked, because TCP offers zero guarantees about when data will be delivered. Even if you know exactly the number of bytes to expect, you have no reason to believe all of those bytes will become available immediately. There aren't enough ...

Comment: ... details in this question to offer even a stab at some specific advice as to how to improve the design. You need to spend some time researching asynchronous network I/O in .NET, and rework the design so your overall program uses it. If and when you run into a _specific_ problem and can post a new question with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, and a detailed explanation of what specifically you need help with, of course please do that.

Comment: Why don't you put two bytes in front of your "message" to store how long the metadata is?

Comment: It’s a reduced snippet. Each connection is handled asynchronously, and I'm using async/await in the code.  The problem is the repeated calls to read a single byte.  That's what I'm trying to optimize out.  This isn't an async/await issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I would only encounter that if I tried to read a larger block of data when the data in the stream ended at the delimiter.  Using the code above it reads exactly to the end of the delimiter.

Comment: @Marco I don't own the other end, unfortunately, otherwise I would.

Comment: _"Using the code above it reads exactly to the end of the delimiter"_ -- you misunderstand. There is no guarantee you will _ever_ receive the delimiter, never mind _when_ it will arrive. The fact that the code works now is not a guarantee; it's _typical_, granted...delays in delivery of data are rare. But you cannot _count_ on them not happening. In any case, the fact remains that the whole design is broken.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm aware of that.  That's not the problem I'm trying to solve with this question.  It's not a concern with the current implementation; disconnection handling, delays, and various other scenarios are handled just fine.  I'm simply looking to optimize how quickly I can get to the end of the delimiter, and reading a single byte at a time doesn't seem to be the most efficient.  I'm not sure where in my problem description above I ever mentioned anything about solving for cases where I'll never receive the delimiter, is the question not clear?

Comment: No, your question is not clear at all. You say your concern with reading more bytes than just up to the delimiter is that the data might not arrive. But a) you _will_ read whatever data is available (so if the delimiter's going to show up at all, the worst that will happen is you'll receive _too much_ and have to keep that around for later), and b) the whole idea of "blocking" in a network I/O thread is anathema to correctly-written network I/O code in the first place. If you can fix your question so that it includes a [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, what ...

Comment: ... you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with, that would be good. Otherwise, it's not clear at all what sort of help you need here.

Comment: My problem is that reading one byte at a time to get to the delimiter seems inefficient and slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see those `Read(array, offset, count)` return values you are putting into a variable `bytesRead` and then happily ignoring?

Those (along with setting the socket in non-blocking mode) are the solution to your problem.  Then you can access "everything received so far" without getting stuck waiting for enough extra data to arrive to fill your array.

Even in blocking mode, ignoring that return value is a bug, because when the socket is gracefully shut down, you will get a partial read where `bytesRead < bytesRequested`

---

Regarding your concerns about how to save the extra data for later, Microsoft provided a class for that.  See `System.IO.BufferedStream` and the example:

> The following code examples show how to use the BufferedStream class over the NetworkStream class to increase the performance of certain I/O operations. Start the server on a remote computer before starting the client. Specify the remote computer name as a command-line argument when starting the client. Vary the dataArraySize and streamBufferSize constants to view their effect on performance.

- Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream

Not shown in the example is that you still need to put the socket into non-blocking mode to avoid having the BufferedStream block until an entire buffer chunk is received.  The `Socket` class provides the `Blocking` property to make that easy.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking

Comment: Yes @BenVoigt the actual code is using bytes read.  As I mentioned in the question I reduced the code down to something very small (code reduced for brevity, removed checking of negative cases, etc).  The issue I'm trying to solve isn't graceful shutdown.  It's how to improve performance of reading the stream up to the end of the delimiter.

Comment: @joelc That doesn't change the answer, which is "read (from a non-blocking socket) with a big buffer for efficiency, and if only one more byte was received on the network, you'll get `bytesRead == 1`"

Comment: There may be data after the delimiter Ben.  After my code reaches the delimiter, the stream needs to be handled by another function, which is why I don't want to read past the delimiter.  I want to read up to the delimiter in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: @joelc: You clearly knew how to handle reading extra, it was in the section of your question that you have now deleted (but is still visible in the edit history).

Comment: Hi Ben - yes - I figured if I just read a large block, which included the delimiter (and potentially part of the data following the delimiter), I'd have to figure out someway to also get the over-read data into the function that would (normally) consume the stream from the point where the data begins.  I guess there isn't a good way to just read up to the end of the delimiter without just using a large buffer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @joelc: The "good" way is to have just one level of buffering in your buffered I/O, and put  a `Stream` implementation on top of that so that it becomes transparent to the programmer.  That means that your function processing the data shouldn't accept `NetworkStream` specifically but should work with any sort of stream.  Only the buffering layer should care about the underlying transport details.

Comment: @joelc: Such a thing already exists in the framework, see edit.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!